# object.draw() shows last defined image on al object.draw() calls

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

i'm pretty new with javascript/ programming and i'm experimenting with some basic canvas game script i wrote. I'm trying to make 4 background images move left or right at a different speed on a key event. So far so good, it works fine.

The problem starts when i draw the 4 images on the canvas. Al the x,y and h,w settings work fine, accept the image itself. on de canvas it shows the same (last defined) image for al the drawings. I have now idea where i went wrong on this one.

Hope you guys can help me out!
Thnx in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas test game/ movement</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="1000"></canvas>
<footer></footer>
</body>
<script>
    var canvas  = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            img     = new Image();

    var newImage = function(){
        this.image = function(name){
            img.src="./images/" + name;
        };
        this.setSize = function(w, h){
            this.w = w;
            this.h = h;
        };
        this.setPosition = function(x, y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        };
        this.setSpeed = function(speed){
            this.speed = speed;
        };
        this.changePosition = function(direction){
            if (direction){
                this.x = this.x + this.speed;
            } else {
                this.x = this.x - this.speed;
            }
        };
        this.draw = function(){
            context.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        };
    };

    var move = function(direction){
        achtergrond.changePosition(direction);
        maan.changePosition(direction);
        landschapAchter.changePosition(direction);
        landschapVoor.changePosition(direction);
    };

    var achtergrond = new newImage();
    achtergrond.image("galaxy.png");
    achtergrond.setSize(1600, 1000);
    achtergrond.setPosition(0, 0);
    achtergrond.setSpeed(0);

    var maan = new newImage();
    maan.image("maan.png");
    maan.setSize(400, 400);
    maan.setPosition(200, 100);
    maan.setSpeed(1);

    var landschapAchter = new newImage();
    landschapAchter.image("landschapAchter.png");
    landschapAchter.setSize(3200, 500);
    landschapAchter.setPosition(0, 450);
    landschapAchter.setSpeed(2);

    var landschapVoor = new newImage();
    landschapVoor.image("landschapVoor.png"); // In the browser all 4 (achtergrond, maan, landschapAchter and landschapVoor) objects show this img on object.draw()
    landschapVoor.setSize(4294, 400);
    landschapVoor.setPosition(0, 600);
    landschapVoor.setSpeed(3);

    var checkKey = function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == '37') {
            move(1);
        } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
            move(0);
        }
        // Move images on key event
        context.clearRect ( 0, 0 , 1600 , 1000 );
        achtergrond.draw();
        maan.draw();
        landschapAchter.draw();
        landschapVoor.draw();
    };

    window.onload = function(){
        maan.draw();
        landschapAchter.draw();
        landschapVoor.draw();
        achtergrond.draw();
    }

    document.onkeydown = checkKey;
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed this with while specifying  src tag :)

```
var newImage = function(){
    this.image = function(name){
        this.src="./images/" + name;
    };
```

Try this.

Comment: Yes, i knew it was something stupid i overlooked! Thank you @Rajesh Dhiman! It works great now.